# Эмуляция мыши в окне игры

Tags: c++, c, winapi

может кто знает чем можно эмулировать Щелчок мыши в окне игры.
Но без использования Mouse_event() изначально программа работает с GetPixel() в сочетании с GetCursorPos(), Есть ли библиотека на 'Си' and 'C++', что бы использовать что-то другое  вместо Mouse_event()? Есть отдельный драйвер Inerception, но он мне не подойдет по ряду причин.

Comment: а события `WM_*` не устраивают?

Comment: Хмм... Интересно я почитаю об этом спасибо